# How to display hours between two dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

Two datefield

```
<input type="text" name="from date" >

<input type="text" name="to date" >
```

Example : If fromdate is `2011-09-12` and todate is `2011-09-15`

ouput should display :

display every hour

```
 2011-09-12 00:00:00
 2011-09-12 01:00:00
 2011-09-12 02:00:00
 2011-09-12 03:00:00
 2011-09-12 04:00:00
.
.
.
.
.
2011-09-15 23:00:00
```

it is possible in mysql code or php

Comment: this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) might be helpful for you

Comment: That is a `php` question and the problem must **not** be solved at *Database Level*. So, answer have nothing about `mysql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$from_date_time = strtotime($_POST['from_date']);
$to_date_time = strtotime($_POST['to_date']);

while ($from_date_time < $to_date_time) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $from_date_time);
    $from_date_time += 3600;
}
```

Comment: @Debiprasad :Thank you very much .It is working fine.one question if we remove strtotime means,it not working .what is main use of the strtotime

Comment: @user966460 It parses about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp. Please check this on PHP Manual [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

hello in MS SQL server 2005 you can do this by the following code of using CTE..

```
declare @dateh table(ind int identity(1,1),date1 smalldatetime,date2 smalldatetime)

insert into @dateh select '1/1/2011','1/2/2011'

select * from @dateh

;with T as
(
    select date1,date2 from @dateh as d
    union all
    select dateadd(hh,1,date1),date2 From T 
    where  dateadd(hh,1,date1)<= date2
)
Select date1 from T
```